# How can I change the document color space to P3 in Sketch?

Tags: javascript, macos, plugins, sketchapp, cocoascript

I'm trying to create a plugin for Sketch, and I'd like to know how to change the color space of a Sketch document file to P3. Can anyone help?

```
var onRun = function(context) {
    var doc = context.document;

    doc.changeColorSpace(ColorSpace.P3, true);
    var colorName = [doc colorSpace];

    doc.showMessage("Color space changed to Display " + colorName);
}
```

Why isn’t the code working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted seems to be that you're trying to call a new Sketch JS API method (`changeColorSpace()`) on an object derived from the old API (`context`).

Here's how I'd rewrite your snippet to use the modern Sketch API only:

```
// 1. Make sure to import all required APIs once in the beginning of your script
var Document = require('sketch/dom').Document
var UI = require('sketch/ui')

var onRun = function(context) {
  // 2. Ignore the `context` argument here and obtain all required objects
  // (the current document in this case) via Sketch API explicitly
  let document = Document.getSelectedDocument()
  document.changeColorSpace(Document.ColorSpace.P3, true)

  UI.message('Color space changed to: ' + document.colorSpace)
}
```